# Spring non primary annotation in Java config

Tags: java, spring

In XML config I can write (Class2 extends Class1):

```
<bean name="bean1" class="com.comp.Class1" primary="true"/>
<bean name="bean2" class="com.comp.Class2" primary="false"/>
```

But how can I reach the same effect using Java config? It's seems that place only one @Primary on bean1.
But then I got error "expected single matching bean but found 2" when autowiring by interface which implemented by Class1.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already know about qualifiers and your use-case is not to use that.

I think something like below should work in your case.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public Employee JohnEmployee() {
        return new Employee("John");
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public Employee TonyEmployee() {
        return new Employee("Tony");
    }
}
```

```
MAIN JAVA CLASS

AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context
  = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

Employee employee = context.getBean(Employee.class);
System.out.println(employee);
```